# osmdroid offline map not loading the tiles

Tags: android, osmdroid, offlineapps

I need to see the offline tile in App

i have downloaded the tiles using **"Mobile Atlas Creator 2.0.0 beta 1"** configurations as below

[image]

The tile zip file is in the

```
/mnt/sdcard/osmdriod/tiles.zip
```

MyActivity code as below

```
MapView mapView = new MapView(this); //constructor

    mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest", 0, 10, 256, ".png", new String[] {}));

    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(1); //set initial zoom-level, depends on your need
    mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333)); //This point is in Enschede, Netherlands. You should select a point in your map or get it from user's location.
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false); //keeps the mapView from loading online tiles using network connection.
    setContentView(mapView);
```

and the AndriodManifest.xml has these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But the tiles are not shown on the map

[image]
Note:

**osmdroid version**
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.1@aar'

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your osm zip file and check tiles folder name. The tiles folder name in this file must be same with XYTileSource constructor first parameter.
If folder will have name "OpenStreetMap MapQuest" e.g. you probably need to write this:

```
mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("OpenStreetMap MapQuest", 0, 10, 256, ".png", new String[] {}));
```